# Flipping Safari and back to iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, safari, single-sign-on

I am trying to build an iOS app that can do single sign on using Safari. For example, I would like my app to go to https://example.com and then get some token from there and then switch back to the iOS app with that information for me to use in the app.

Currently, I tried using URL Schemes but if from within the app I try to

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURLvURLWithString:@"DevTest://example.com"]];`

it is not going away from my app. It is not flipping to safari, but if I use https://example.com as the URLWithString, it flips to Safari, but I don't know on how to do the callback from Safari.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a link on your website example.com that will start with DevTest://, then when user taps on that link in Safari your app will be started. Don't forget to register "DevTest://" URL scheme in info.plist of your app and implement appDelegate methods for URL launching, see here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Inter-AppCommunication/Inter-AppCommunication.html